# Grails 2.3.8 Stacktrace doesn't show any of my calling code

Tags: grails

I have a method in my controller that is being called from somewhere. As far as I can tell, nothing in my code is calling it, so I added a stack trace output line to see if i can tell where it's getting called from. With this, here is what the method looks like:

```
def remediationSearch() {
        println " "; println ">>>>>> remediationSearch() start at " + System.nanoTime()
        new Exception("why are you calling me?!?!").printStackTrace()
        def resultList
        if (params.rerender) {
            println "<><><> remediationsearch() called with rerender."
            resultList = recordSearchService.individualSearch(session.oldIndRemedParams)
        }
        else {
            params.selectedBatch = selectedBatch
            session.oldIndRemedParams = params
            resultList = recordSearchService.individualSearch(params)
            println "<><><> remediationsearch() called fresh."
        }
        render(template: 'indivSearchResults', model: [resultList: resultList, resultCount: resultList?.size()])
        println "<<<<<< remediationSearch() end at " + System.nanoTime(); println " ";
    }
```

And here is the output of the stacktrace which I can't seem to understand (partly because I'm new to Grails) because I don't seem to see any of my coded functions in it:

```
    >>>>>> remediationSearch() start at 67861365037047
Error |
java.lang.Exception: why are you calling me?!?!
Error |
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessor
Impl.java:57)
Error |
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructor
AccessorImpl.java:45)
Error |
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Error |
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(Refl
ectiveInterceptor.java:986)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:
77)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoC
oerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallS
iteArray.java:57)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractC
allSite.java:182)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractC
allSite.java:190)
Error |
        at com.twc.fatcaone.CustomerController.remediationSearch(CustomerController.groovy
:264)
Error |
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
va:43)
Error |
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInte
rceptor.java:1254)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(M
ixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handl
eAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:354)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.execu
teAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:231)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handl
eURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:197)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handl
eURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:121)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest
(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(Simpl
eControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Grail
sDispatcherServlet.java:355)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.j
ava:856)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServle
t.java:953)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:8
55)
Error |
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:
829)
Error |
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:303)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentC
achingFilter.java:198)
Error |
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingF
ilterProxy.java:343)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterP
roxy.java:260)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilt
er.java:101)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilt
er.java:101)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilt
er.java:101)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.jav
a:748)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispat
cher.java:486)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.
java:411)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.ja
va:338)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(We
bUtils.java:332)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(We
bUtils.java:297)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(We
bUtils.java:288)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInterna
l(UrlMappingsFilter.java:217)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilt
er.java:107)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.executeFilterChainWith
WrappedResponse(GrailsPageFilter.java:233)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPa
geFilter.java:208)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFil
ter.java:153)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
        at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.gro
ovy:45)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInter
nal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilt
er.java:107)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(
HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilt
er.java:107)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(Charact
erEncodingFilter.java:88)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilt
er.java:107)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingF
ilterProxy.java:343)
Error |
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterP
roxy.java:260)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFil
terChain.java:241)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain
.java:208)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:
220)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:
122)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:11
6)
Error |
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
Error |
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processo
r.java:1040)
Error |
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractPr
otocol.java:607)
Error |
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315
)
Error |
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

Error |
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

Error |
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
<><><> remediationsearch() called fresh.
<<<<<< remediationSearch() end at 67863898745818
```

`

Comment: It does: `com.twc.fatcaone.CustomerController.remediationSearch(CustomerController.groovy
:264)`. Rest what you see is layers of Tomcat container calls and Spring MVC doing the trick to reach to `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: @dmahapatro The frame you refer to there is the method he is asking about, not the method that is invoking the method he is asking about.  I don't know what you mean by "It does".

Comment: Question: "Grails 2.3.8 Stacktrace doesn't show any of my code" Answer: It does... @JeffScottBrown

Comment: I assumed that he meant that it wasn't his code which was invoking the method in question (the remediationSearch method).

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Your assumption is correct. I am still at a loss to figure it out.

Comment: @dmahapatro I did word the question a bit poorly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare this output to a "real" request you'll see basically the same thing. This is what I'd expect to see - the various filters in the filter chain get called, then the servlet's service method (note that the servlet is `GrailsDispatcherServlet` which extends Spring's `DispatcherServlet`), then it goes to `doPost` which is weird because that's a POST request, but this seemed like it'd be a GET, then to `doDispatch` (where Grails figures out where to route the request), and then to `SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle`.

There's only 1 Spring MVC controller in a Grails app, `SimpleGrailsController`. It acts as a bridge between Grails controllers and Spring MVC. Grails controllers are just Groovy classes, so they can't be registered as Spring MVC controllers, but instead this controller instance handles all requests and with help from `MixedGrailsControllerHelper` which tells it the controller and method to use (based on a reverse URL mapping from the requested url to an entry in `URLMappings.groovy`), it uses reflection to call the controller method. That's why there's a `Method.invoke` just before your controller action. The springloaded `jlrMethodInvoke` is there because springloaded adds reloading support in dev mode, but otherwise it can be ignored.

Your best bet is to run the app in debug mode and set some breakpoints so you can figure out what url is being requested. Before that though - set the Log4j level for these classes to debug and maybe that'll have something useful.

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie but it took me a couple of days to figure out how to do everything you said just in the last paragraph. I am now running in debug mode and logging accordingly. After the last validly called(from my code) function in my controller finishes executing, I step through the program step by step and I am thrown into framework code. There I see objects very similar in names to what I saw in the stacktrace. Then all the sudden, my function remediationSearch() gets called, I still don't know from where because (continued into next comment)

Comment: because this is what I get from my own log statements:               >>>>>> auth() started at 113589243808961
<><><> Tracing action /customer/remediationSearch
<<<<<< auth() ended at 113589261281183  
>>>>>> remediationSearch() start at 113589262752241
Error |
java.lang.Exception: why are you calling me?!?! (continued into next comment)

Comment: Auth is called from my before interceptor so that's valid, but then nothing is logged between that and the invalid (not from my code) call to remeciationSearch(). You mentioned about looking for a URL, where and when should I lookout for this?

Comment: Look for code that gets the value of `request.forwardURI` (note that this isn't in the interface, it's dynamic) - that's the one closest to the originally requested one, but `request.getRequestURI()` and `request.getRequestURL()` will be helpful also